# Content outside body tag

Tags: html, css

I'm using:

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}

section {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

And it seems all the content that appears below .full aren't included in the body tag, 
is there a way to rectify this? Or does it not matter that it is like this.

I tried changing the overflow value and change the height to auto but nothing seems to work.

```
<body>

<section class="full">

     <div class="center"></div>

</section> <!-- Everything below here appears outside <body> -->

<section class="main">

<header>
<!-- Nav goes here -->
</header>

<content>
<!-- Main divs are here -->
</content>

</section> 

</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'outside of body'? don't you have a vertical scroll?

Comment: With `height: 100%` on `section`, all other content is going to overflow `body`. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Why do you set section width and height to 100% ? Looks for me that this is messing up everything. How should it look in the end?

Comment: Using devtools in chrome and selecting the body tag, the html document is say 2000px long but the body ends at 1000px (height of viewport).

Comment: @Steven_Harris_ `height` does not allow stretching, so giving it `100%` would force it to stay at viewport size. Maybe you want [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)?

Comment: I tried min-height: 100% for body but this causes <section> not to display. Is having the rest of the content overflowing body ok?

Comment: The `<body>` tag encloses everything on the page.  You are confusing the view port (screen) with the body of the page.  If you get the lingo right then it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have a CSS rule that gives 100% height to all the `<section>`'s in the markup.

The first section (that with the 'full') takes all the view port height (that is possible only because you also gave `html,body` 100% height - which is the view port's actual height), causing the browser to add a vertical scroll that allows you to see the rest of the content.

See this demo [here](http://jsbin.com/axOqUDe/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 1):

Your webpage has two `<section>` elements each with height 100%, so the second one appears below the fold.

Answer (score 0):

A height of `100%` doesn't mean "100% height of the content" but "100% of the height of the parent element". For `html` and `body`, the viewport is the parent. So if your browser window is 1000 pixels high, that will be the size of `body`.

The `section` element gets the same height as `body` (i.e. each of them will be 1000 pixels).

So the first step is to remove the `height: 100%` everywhere. The next step would then be to tell us which effect you want to achieve.